# Using switch statement to evaluate regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, switch-statement

I'm trying to manage my `if` statements into a `switch` statement to evaluate regex, but I don't know how I can go about it. I tried many possibilities but cannot do it. See code below, is it right?:

```
var username = $('input.username'),
    phone = $('input.phone'),
    numRegex = /^[0-9]/i,
    alphaRegex = /^[a-zA-Z]/i,
    usernameVal = username.val(),
    phoneVal = phone.val();

switch (phoneVal) {

  case numRegex.test(phoneVal):
    console.log('Only digits please.');
    break;

  default:
    console.log('It\'s all good.');

}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: So long as those vars are in scope just `switch (false) {`

Comment: I believe switch only allows for testing one condition

Comment: Why you are tying to build your own validation scheme while you can easly be accomplished by something like [jQuery  validation](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validate/)

Comment: @Emmanuel N: Because that's what my company wants.

Comment: @Alex K. & m.edmondson: I have modified my code to only 1 expression. But it still not doing anything.

Comment: Why are you using a `switch`?

Comment: @Tom: Because I have a long list of regex for evaluation, so it makes sense to use a `switch` instead of having several `if` statements all over the place.

Comment: But you want to check whether the tests return `true` or `false`, not to compare their return value (`true` or `false`) with `phoneVal`. This is not the way to use `switch`. It seems you need a chain of `if`s (an `if`, lots of `else if`s, and an `else`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this kind of defeats the point of the `switch` statement having the conditions in the `case` statements. It's intent is to test multiple outputs given a single input.

Perhaps if JavaScript supported multiple inputs (or [destructuring](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3adestructuring) of arrays) in a `switch..case` I could see something like this:

```
switch (numRegex.test(phoneVal), alphaRegex.test(usernameVal)) {
    case false, false:
        console.log('Neither are valid.');
        break;

    case true, false:
        console.log('Invalid username.');
        break;

    /* snip */

    default:
        console.log('All\'s good.');
}
```

But alas, I'd say sticking with `if..else` is a better and easier to follow/understand option, in this case:

```
if (numRegex.test(phoneVal)) {
    console.log('Only digits please.');
    return false;
} else if (alphaRegex.test(usernameVal)) {
    console.log('Only alpha-numeric please.');
    return false;
} else {
    console.log('It\'s all good.');
    return true;
}
```

Comment: But some language do accept multiple expression in the switch, but not javascript...!!? Guess I have to use `if`'s all over the place. Anyways thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using each regex once why not just refactor this into a block of ternaries?

Maybe something like this:

```
/^\S/.test($('#name').val()) !== true
? invalidEls.push('name:invalid')
: invalidEls.push('name:valid');

$('#phone').val().match(/^(1-?)?([2-9]\d{2}|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/)
? invalidEls.push('phone:valid')
: invalidEls.push('phone:invalid');

$('#email').val().match(/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]){1,}?/)
? invalidEls.push('email:valid')
: invalidEls.push('email:invalid');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another similar pattern;

```
try {
    if (!alphaRegex.test(usernameVal))
        throw ('Only letters please.');

    if (!numRegex.test(phoneVal))
         throw ('Only digits please.');

    ...
    return true;
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```